# Is it possible to control and transmit electromagnetic radiation of allowed frequency with Android device?

Tags: hardware, cellular-radio

I understand the following things about smartphones

- A smartphone has various hardware that functions wirelessly by transmitting and receiving electromagnetic waves.
- Things like Wifi, Bluetooth, and phone calling all work by transmitting and receiving electromagnetic waves.
- The frequencies that this hardware can emit are fixed. It cannot work in all frequencies. It can work in only part of the frequency spectrum.

Let us take the following example.
I want to use a smartphone to emit an electromagnetic wave of a particular frequency, say X Hz.
If this particular frequency is supported by the hardware, is it possible to control/emit this signal of this particular frequency, like using any apps?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Take note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not putting any restriction for apps-only. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: A Wifi or Bluetooth devices works in 2.4GHz band but each chip is limited to Wifi or Bluetooth specific signals. Only a SDR (Software Defined Radio) can emit signals defined by software. If you want to generate frequencies defined by software I would recommend to look into decent SDR hardware boards. An Android device is as far as I know not good as SDR hardware.